# When trying to call IConfiguration.Get() the result is always null

Tags: c#, configuration

I'm getting a strange issue when trying to use the IConfiguration.
My code is as follows:

```
public class testconfigtests
{
    public void DoTest()
    {            
        var testClass = new TestClass()
        {
            Name = "hello"                
        };

        var config = new Dictionary<string, string>()
        {
            { "Section1:section2",  JsonSerializer.Serialize(testClass) }
        };

        var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .AddInMemoryCollection(config)
            .Build();

        var testConfig = new GetTestClassConfig<TestClass>();
        var c = testConfig.GetTestAsync(configuration);
        // c is always null
    }
}

public class TestClass
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class GetTestClassConfig<T>
{
    public T GetTestAsync(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        var section = configuration.GetSection("Section1:section2");
        return section.Get<T>();
    }

}
```

The problem that I have is `result` is always null. My understanding is that config.Get<> would return a serialized version of the class, but it just returns null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use AddInMemoryCollection it doesn't use any JSON deserialization.
As the method name suggests, it's just a collection.
Look how the structure of the configuration looks when you use it.

[image]

Now compare the structure of the configuration when you actually use the method that supports building from JSON.

```
public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var testClass = new TestClass()
        {
            Name = "hello"          
        };

        var configJson = new Dictionary<string, object>()
        {
            { "Section1:section2", testClass }
        };

        var configurationJson = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .AddJsonStream(new MemoryStream(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(JsonSerializer.Serialize(configJson))))
            .Build();

        var testConfig = new GetTestClassConfig<TestClass>();
        var c = testConfig.GetTestAsync(configurationJson);
        
        Console.WriteLine("Result: " + c.Name);
    }
}

public class TestClass
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class GetTestClassConfig<T>
{
    public T GetTestAsync(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        IConfigurationSection section = configuration.GetSection("Section1:section2");
        return section.Get<T>();
    }

}
```

[image]

As you can see configuration structure now actually contains keys with fields from your class.

Comment: Changing this doesn't seem to make any difference - the result is still returned as null

Comment: I edited code, try maybe a full one and verify the result